# Can not send value

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, variables

i'm trying to send one parameter from funtion to one any control on the page but i can not do that. what i'm doing wrong?
i checked that the paramter (PDX) is getting right values and they are changing but nothing shown on the any control on the page. (like textbox, listbox etc. i tried all )

```
private void OnPDXDataArrived(string PDX, bool Header)
{
    TextBox1.Text += PDX;
    PDXDataArrived(PDX, Header);
}

public string blabla;

private void PDXDataArrived(string PDX, bool Header)
{

        int FieldCount = int.Parse(txtUpload_Fields.Text);
        int nCnt = 0;

        if (Header == true)
        {
            ListBox4.Items.Add(PDX);
            TextBox1.Text += PDX;
            blabla += PDX.ToString();
            TextBox1.Text = blabla;
            Console.WriteLine(blabla);
        }
        else
        {
            strTemplete += PDX + "\r";
                string nStemp = strTemplete.Substring(0, strTemplete.Length - 1);

                datammm = nStemp.Split(new string[] { "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                for (int dx = 0; dx < datammm.Length; dx++) ListBox4.Items.Add(datammm[dx]);

    }
}
```

Comment: how are you adding the controls and where?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: controls are on the same asp page. like textbox, listbox, ..